# Unable to DROP or MODIFY a column because row size is too large

Tags: mariadb-10.2

I've tried to `ALTER` the table to `DROP` the unused columns or to change the data type of some `VARCHAR` columns to `TEXT`, but I always get this error:

> ERROR 1118 (42000) at line 1: Row size too large (> 8126). Changing some columns to TEXT or BLOB may help. In current row format, BLOB prefix of 0 bytes is stored inline.

The `ROW_FORMAT` is already set to `DYNAMIC`.

It won't let me do anything to make the table smaller, so I'm stuck.

I am running MariaDb

> mysqld  Ver 10.2.27-MariaDB-10.2.27+maria~xenial-log for debian-linux-gnu on x86_64 (mariadb.org binary distribution)

Any ideas on how to get past this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Fixed the problem by converting a bunch of `VARCHAR` columns to `TEXT`.

It was failing when I tried to convert just one or two columns at a time. - [user184048](https://dba.stackexchange.com/users/184048/lfjeff)